# How to map relationship while testing spring data jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

### Issue

I'm writing test code for a simple service layer using jpa data entity, but entity's relationship doesn't seem to work properly.

I googled but couldn't find an answer. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Please check the code below

### Codes

#### (0) test property

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;MODE=MySQL
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

#### (1) entities

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Authority> authList;

    public Set<String> getAuthName() {
        if (this.authList == null || this.authList.isEmpty()) return null;

        Set<String> authNameSet = new HashSet<>();
        authList.forEach(e -> authNameSet.add(e.getStringName()));
        return authNameSet;
    }
}

//----------

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "authorities")
public class Authority implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 10)
    private AuthorityName name;
}
```

#### (2) repositories

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
//----------
@Repository
public interface AuthorityRepository extends CrudRepository<Authority, Long> {

    List<Authority> findByUser(User user);
}
```

#### (3) service layer to test

```java
@Service
public class AuthorityService {

    // this is the method i want to test
    public boolean isUserHaveAuthorityOf(User user, AuthorityName authOf) {
        if (user == null || authOf == null) throw new InternalError("msg");
        if (user.getAuthName() == null) return false;

        return user.getAuthName().contains(authOf.name());
    }
}
```

#### (4) test code

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
class AuthorityServiceTest {

    @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired private AuthorityRepository authorityRepository;
    @Autowired private AuthorityService authorityService;
    private User sampleUser;

     @BeforeEach
    void setupDB() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1);
        user.setUsername("name");
        user.setPassword("passwd");
        user.setEmail("email@dot.com");
        user.setBirth("20000101");
        user.setAddress("addr");
        user.setAddressDetail("addrDetail");
        user.setZipCode("12345");
        user.setDeleted(false);
        user.setDisabled(false);
        user.setBlock(false);
        userRepository.save(user);
        sampleUser = user;
    }

    @Test
    void testIsUserHaveAuthorityOfNormalCase() {
        assertFalse(authorityService.isUserHaveAuthorityOf(sampleUser, AuthorityName.USER));
        assertFalse(authorityService.isUserHaveAuthorityOf(sampleUser, AuthorityName.ADMIN));

        Authority auth = new Authority();
        auth.setUser(sampleUser);
        auth.setName(AuthorityName.USER);
        authorityRepository.save(auth);

        assertNotNull(sampleUser.getAuthName()); // it is null!


        // I thought it was because of a caching, so I get a new user from the db.
        User flushedUser = userRepository.findById(sampleUser.getId()).get(); 
        assertNotNull(flushedUser.getAuthName()); // but still null

    }


    @AfterEach
    void cleanDB() {
        authorityRepository.deleteAll();
        userRepository.deleteAll();
    }

}

Thank you
```

Comment: You can mock the service

Comment: @Vishal 
Does mocking the Service help to test the Service layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bidirectional relationship between User and Authority so you should keep the relationship in sync. As well as setting the User in an Authority you should also add the Authority to the the User

```
public void addAuthority(Authority authority) {
    if (authList == null) {
        authList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    authList.add(authority);
    authority.setUser(this);
}
```

It would also be helpful to see how you are persisting the sampleUser

Comment: Thanks for commenting. However, it seems that I did not present the point well in the question.
I was wondering why the relationship is mapped properly in the product environment (mariadb) and not in the test environment (h2) even with the same code.
I need to change the question.

Comment: before I Change whole question, i add how do i persist sampleUser on `(4) test code`

Comment: Save method will return persisted entity, 'sampleUser = userRepository.save(user);'